# cmake error libcurl not found, but libcurl4 is installed

Tags: c++, cmake, game-engine

I am trying to compile the Springlobby version 268 client from the open source game TA-Spring. However the newest version (271) compiles just fine. But when I try to compile version 268 I get the CMake-error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:163 (message):
  CURL: Required feature libcurl is not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/CMakeLists.txt:127 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I am compiling on Debian testing and tried the libraries `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, `libcurl-gnutls-dev` and `libcurl4-nss-dev` all without success.
game: https://springrts.com
lobby 0.271: https://github.com/springlobby/springlobby
lobby 0.268: https://github.com/springlobby/springlobby/tree/0.268
install from source: https://github.com/springlobby/springlobby/wiki/Installfromsource

Building the lobby from git repo:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/springlobby/springlobby.git
cd springlobby
cmake .
make
make install
```

The Springlobby version 271 uses `libcurl4-openssl-dev` but version 268 seemingly links to an older libcurl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 268 incorrectly calls `find_package` ([src/CMakeLists.txt:127](https://github.com/springlobby/springlobby/blob/0.268/src/CMakeLists.txt#L127)):

```
FIND_PACKAGE( CURL REQUIRED libcurl )
```

The last parameter `libcurl` is interpreted (according to [find_package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)) as the element of `COMPONENTS` list, and in case of [FindCURL.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html) it is treated as PROTOCOL/FEATURE specification. Obviously, `libcurl` means neither protocol nor feature.

Commit https://github.com/springlobby/springlobby/commit/252c4cb156c1442ed9b4faec3f26265bc7c295ff fixes this call to

```
FIND_PACKAGE(CURL REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but does this apply also to a possible backport of Springlobby to version 268 ?

Comment: "does this apply also to...?" - What do you mean by "this"? In your version you could check how `find_package` is called for `CURL`, and remove `libcurl` parameter if this call has it. (I am not a developer of the project you are trying to build.)

Answer (score 0):

The Springlobby 0.268 supports the older lobby servers with most players on it as well as the newer ones.
So in case you want to compile and use the older 0.268 Springlobby, you have to git clone the current version like I already wrote and then cherry pick the older version by:

```
git checkout 0.268
```

Apply the posted fix by Tsyvarev in `src/CMakeLists.txt`, line 127. But you also have to add:

```
#include <string>
```

to the files `src/battlelist.h` and `src/utils/sortutil.h` below the includes at the top of these files.